# Can't instantiate prefab inside prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Evening guys, I have a question of why I can't instantiate prefab inside prefab?

[image]

[image]

ObsSpawner Script:

```
public GameObject[] Spawner;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Spawner = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpawnObj");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    foreach (GameObject spawn in Spawner)
    {
        spawn.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

but if I put the spawner caller outside prefab that will instantiate those obstacles, is it anything wrong with my script?

Comment: from the first image I can guess you reference the prefab assets which are just files and can&#39;t be activated and deactivate, you need to reference the instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have references to the prefabs. Just iterate through and `Instantiate` them:

```
public GameObject[] Spawner;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    foreach (GameObject spawn in Spawner)
    {
        Instantiate(spawn);
    }
}
```

Comment: why I didn't think of it there, so I just missing instantiate :D

Comment: @Syarifabdurrahman Glad to help :) Please consider clicking the `✔`  button so people who find this question on the search page know you found an answer that worked. it also gives me some more reputation